# ORA-24344: success with compilation error / trigger

Tags: sql, psql

not sure why im getting this error, no real clue of what im doing with psql but if anyone can help id appreciate it

```
create or replace trigger gender_check
before insert or update of gender
on volunteer
for each row
begin
    if (:new.volunteer.gender != 'M' or :new.volunteer.gender != 'F')
        then    raise_application_error(-20601,
        'Gender is invalid, please insert M or F');
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition should be:

```
if (:new.gender <> 'M' and :new.gender <> 'F')
```

With the `or`, *all* non-NULL values will pass the condition, because `'M'` <> `'F'`.

The important change is the *and* and the removal of `volunteer`, which appears to be the table name.

A better way to write this is:

```
if (:new.gender not in ('M', 'F'))
```